# Jquery orientationchange

Tags: jquery

When I use the orientationchange it never gets fired when checking on Ipad.

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange',function(e){
   alert("orientationchange");
});
```

Is there something I'm missing. 
I'm using jQuery v@1.8.0

Comment: Did you include jQuery *and* jQuery mobile?

Comment: Just jquery as I said above in my post jQuery v@1.8.0. So orientationchange is not part of Jquery only jquery mobile

Comment: You need [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), that's what contains the [`orientationchange` event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/).

Comment: I added the Jquery Mobile and it's still not firing. I have both Jquery and Jquery mobile on the page now

Comment: Try updating to jQuery 1.9.  Also, try using `$(window).on` instead of `$(window).bind`.

Comment: I actually get an error when I added it to the page. TypeError: t.matchMedia(...) is null. It only happens when using it in Iframe.

Comment: We'd need to see the rest of the code to help you.  What's `t`?  What's `t.matchMedia`?

Comment: I don't use t.t.matchMedia anywhere in my code. I only get this error when adding Jquery mobile to my page. There isn't any code just adding it to an Iframe is causing an error.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

That which jQuery mobile provides is merely this.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {  // IE 6, 7 check
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
        // do your stuff here
    }, false);
}
```